# Chromedriver error "Chrome version must be >= 52" using Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to setup [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#guide), and am using the **latest chromedriver** which says it [supports chrome v52-54](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.24/notes.txt). BUT, when I try to run the tests, it says **`'Error: Chrome version must be >=52.0.2743.'`** Here's everything that I'm using:

- [ChromeDriver 2.24](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
- [Selenium 2.53.1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
- [Nightwatch v0.9.8](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#installation)
- [Node v6.5.0](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- [Java v1.7.0_111](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

**Project Structure**

```
|-- nightwatch.json
|-- bin/
|   |-- chromedriver
|   |-- selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
|-- tests/
|   |-- sample.js
|-- results/
|-- screens/
|-- node_modules/
|   |-- (lots of modules here)
```

And here is my [configuration file](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file) for nightwatch:

**./nightwatch.json**

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "results",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "results",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "screens/"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Running Tests**

I run the tests like this:

```
nightwatch tests/
```

**Error**

And I get the following output:

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  3500

[Sample] Test Suite
=======================

Running:  Demo test Google

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ sessionId: null,
  status: 13,
  state: 'unhandled error',
  value: 
   { message: 'unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 52.0.2743.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 1.42 seconds\nBuild info: version: \'2.53.1\', revision: \'a36b8b1\', time: \'2016-06-30 17:37:03\'\nSystem info: host: \'N/A\', ip: \'N/A\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'3.2.0-56-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_111\'\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
     suppressed: [],
     localizedMessage: 'unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 52.0.2743.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 1.42 seconds\nBuild info: version: \'2.53.1\', revision: \'a36b8b1\', time: \'2016-06-30 17:37:03\'\nSystem info: host: \'N/A\', ip: \'N/A\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'3.2.0-56-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_111\'\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
     buildInformation: 
      { releaseLabel: '2.53.1',
        buildTime: '2016-06-30 17:37:03',
        class: 'org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo',
        buildRevision: 'a36b8b1',
        hCode: 1900167016 },
     cause: null,
     systemInformation: 'System info: host: \'N/A\', ip: \'N/A\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'3.2.0-56-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_111\'',
     supportUrl: null,
     class: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException',
     additionalInformation: '\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
     hCode: 1299270263,
     screen: null },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  hCode: 1144687147 }
```

Anyone know how to resolve this error?

**`Chrome version must be >= 52.0.2743.0`**

Does chromedriver use my local copy of chrome? Do I need to update my actual chrome?

Comment: Yes, chromedriver does use your local copy of Chrome. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does chromedriver use my local copy of chrome? Do I need to update my actual chrome?

Yes, [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) is a executable that selenium webdriver uses to control chrome.

So selenium webdriver launch your installed chrome from your default location or custom location which you tell to selenium webdriver during initialising [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).

So basically  [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) executable just use to talking between chrome browser and selenium webdriver to control it that doesn't mean it launches their own chrome browser. It uses your installed chrome browser.

So yes, you need to update your actual installed chrome.

Comment: I do have updated my Chrome to the latest version and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ChesterRivas what version of chromedriver are you using?? And what error are you getting??

Comment: @ChesterRivas  By "ChromeDriver" he's not referring to your Chrome *browser*. The ChromeDriver is code that Protractor uses to control Chrome for running your tests (it actually creates a small dev server to load your site on to test it). See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 12):

Yes, ChromeDriver uses your local Chrome installation. In case you prefer not to upgrade your Chrome installation, you can specify a version of ChromeDriver that would work with the installed Chrome version.

You can find the compatible Chrome versions for different ChromeDriver releases at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/notes.txt (change "2.25" to a newer version if your Chrome version is newer than what is listed there).

If your test framework uses the Node.js `webdriver-manager`, you can simply install the required ChromeDriver version (keeping any already installed versions) using (e.g. for version `2.20`):

```
webdriver-manager update --chrome --versions.chrome=2.20
```

and specify the appropriate ChromeDriver version when starting Selenium via `webdriver-manager`:

```
webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.20
```

If `webdriver-manager` is unavailable, you can simply download the required ChromeDriver version and use some technique to pass the following parameter to the Selenium server startup command:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/the/desired/chromedriver_version
```

Comment: `In case you prefer not to upgrade your Chrome installation` -- or in case you lack administrative rights to upgrade Chrome! This answer saved me hours of pain. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 this code works:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

**x64**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

**x32**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

**Install/Update**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

[Source](https://tecadmin.net/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: helped me out instaling a newer version of Chrome :) thanks!