# Protractor not working with chromedriver 2.30

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

**EDIT: My chrome driver was up-to-date, but my chrome browser was not. The solution was to downgrade the chrome driver (upgrading Chrome is not an option for me, unfortunately.**

> webdriver-manager update versions.chrome 2.24 //to get exe
>
> webdriver-manager start versions.chrome 2.24 //to run correct exe

**see source of solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542803/2954463**

**also a huge thanks to Barney in the comments.**

---

I need help getting my Protractor up and running. I'm trying to reproduce the `todo-spec` example on the homepage of protractor.org, but I am getting an exception that the Chrome version must be >= 58.

But according to [Google](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), the chromedriver 2.30 in my logs *does* support Chrome 58!

What am I doing wrong? Please note, I am running on a windows environment without admin rights.

---

I'm running webdriver in another terminal

> c:\code\my-project> webdriver-manager start

I have a bare bones protractor config

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

and my spec is copied directly from the homepage of protractor.org

**todo-spec.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

> c:\code\my-project> protractor conf.js

```
c:/code/my-project>protractor conf.js
[14:33:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:33:00] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[14:33:03] E/launcher - session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The ser
ver did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.98 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LFGTZL12', ip: '10.47.203.127', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
[14:33:03] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The ser
ver did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.98 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'LFGTZL12', ip: '10.47.203.127', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at SessionNotCreatedError (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:214:5
)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:5
05:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:7
77:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:709:29)
    at createDriver (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:167:33)
    at Builder.build (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:623:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.ts:60:29)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
[14:33:03] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

c:/code/my-project>
```

Comment: Log message -  Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0. What is your Chrome browser version?

Comment: @Barney - `52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (32-bit)`... and I don't have the ability to update

Comment: Downgrade your chrome driver. ChromeDriver 2.30 supports V58+ `https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromedriver error "Chrome version must be >= 52" using Nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541739/chromedriver-error-chrome-version-must-be-52-using-nightwatch)