# protractor - session not created exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am getting the error below when trying to run Protractor test against chrome.

`session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 59.0.3071.0`

```html
[11:42:23] E/launcher - session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 59.0.3071.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide
any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 6.44 seconds Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z' System info: host: 'PC328569', ip: '10.25.227.179', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
'6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: unknown [11:42:23] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 59.0.3071.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows
NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 6.44 seconds Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z' System info: host: 'PC328569', ip:
'10.25.227.179', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: unknown at WebDriverError (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5) at SessionNotCreatedError
(D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:214:5) at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15) at parseHttpResponse (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
at doSend.then.response (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) From: Task: WebDriver.createSession() at Function.createSession (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
at Function.createSession (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:709:29) at createDriver (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:167:33) at Builder.build (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:623:16)
at Hosted.getNewDriver (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.ts:60:29) at Runner.createBrowser (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39) at q.then.then (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
at _fulfilled (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Balachander\DailyScript\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13) [11:42:23]
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

**Versions of the executables used:** 
webdriver manager - 12.0.6
protractor - 5.1.2
chrome driver - 2.32
Java - 1.8

**What I have tried:**
1.Updating the webdriver to latest version
npm update -g protractor
webdriver-manager update

2.Editing Protractor's config file: node_modules/protractor/config.json
Changing the chrome driver version to whatever you need. eg. "chromedriver": "2.24".Run webdriver-manager update.
But for some reason webdriver-manager always uses chrome driver 2.32.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per Below references you need to update your actual installed chrome.

Update chrome by :- About Google Chrome

Menu -> Help ->

Refer :-

https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1600

[Chromedriver error "Chrome version must be >= 52" using Nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541739/chromedriver-error-chrome-version-must-be-52-using-nightwatch)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Any success? having the same problem here

Comment: I've used the answer of Tiago Garcia on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541739/chromedriver-error-chrome-version-must-be-52-using-nightwatch and was able to update Chrome this way to a newer version