# Laravel dusk chrome driver timeout

Tags: laravel, macos, laravel-dusk

Can anyone help, I am unable to get Laravel dusk to run the default sample test in my current Laravel 5.6 project on mac high sierra.

**Error message**

Time: 2.5 minutes, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-mac","args":["--disable-gpu"]}}}

Operation timed out after 30002 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:286
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:126
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/tests/DuskTestCase.php:40
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:189
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:770
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:190
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:92
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:64
/Users/keith/Desktop/dusk/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21

I have already done the following :

- added the following to app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

use Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider;

...

```
public function register()

{

    if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing')) {

        $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
    }

}
```

- ran 'php artisan dusk:install' in terminal
- set App_URL in .env to http://localhost:8000
- specified the location of chromedriver in DuskTestCase
- start 'php artisan serve' before running 'php artisan dusk'

Repository : https://github.com/KKOA/dusk

Comment: After starting `php artisan serve` your website is available under `http://localhost:8000` in Chrome?

Comment: Have you setup your DuskTestCase yet?

Answer (score 5):

If your function extends from DuskTestCase.php, then you need to increase connection_timeout_in_ms.

Do this by changing driver method to the following:

**DuskTestCase.php**

```
protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            ), 90000, 90000
        );
    }
```

If that dosen't work for some reason then try to `set_time_limit` before `$this->browse`

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this while you instantiate your browser.. the most important is

```
$driver       = retry(5, function () use ($capabilities) {
      return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 60000, 60000);
```

Below is how i instantiate my browser

```
$options      = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless', '--no-sandbox']);
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
  ->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)
  ->setPlatform('Linux');
$driver       = retry(5, function () use ($capabilities) {
  return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 60000, 60000);
}, 50);

$browser = new Browser($this->driver, new ElementResolver($driver, ''));
```

Comment: I needed to update the Chrome installation within my Laravel Homestead Vagrant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227939/470749

Answer (score 1):

You really need to have latest google-chrome and latest chrome driver installed. I used to have only chromium browser and it doesn't work with it. To install latest chrome driver run `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver`.

Comment: This worked for me. I only had chromium browser and it worked when I ran ```php artisan dusk:chrome-driver```