# Laravel Dusk: Curl error thrown for http POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm having some (seemingly random) problems with Dusk. I'm getting the following error, however I do not understand what it means, can someone explain it to me?

```
$php artisan dusk --group=activation
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12475/devtools/browser/19299f29-42c2-4d30-80cb-66d44ef3e6e3
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 18,85 seconds, Memory: 18,00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\CounselorActivationTest::testActivationWithSubscriptionWithPasswordLogin
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session/32a7ccd522f194448bbe7efd19eff65f/url with params: {"url":"http:\/
\/yubu.local\/et-rerum-laborum-et"}

Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:292
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:547
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteExecuteMethod.php:40
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\WebDriverNavigation.php:85
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\Browser.php:111
D:\devYubu\yubu\tests\Browser\tests\userActivation\CounselorActivationTest.php:52
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\TestCase.php:91
D:\devYubu\yubu\tests\Browser\tests\userActivation\CounselorActivationTest.php:95

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

In my code I visit one of my routes:

```
$browser->visit(route('home.subscription', [
      'subscriptionSlug' => $subscription->getAttribute(Subscription::COLUMN_SLUG),
], false))
```

It's driving me kind of crazy, all help is welcome.

In using Windows 10. 
I'm running Dusk on Windows (I have PHP 7.2 installed). 
My application runs on Homestead with PHP 7.0.
I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Did the ChromeDriver update also solve this problem?

Comment: you have the same problem.. please visit here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52515352/2771450

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem. Updating the chromedriver fixed it for me. See this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710137/laravel-dusk-unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value

Comment: For me, it was just a fluke. Without changing anything, I ran dusk again, and it didn't throw that error.