# Laravel Dusk: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm having problems with the Laravel Dusk type() and value() method. I'm getting the following error.

```
$ php artisan dusk --group=activation
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12599/devtools/browser/84028821-2ca1-4d26-b66c-4697d2302117
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 13,35 seconds, Memory: 18,00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\CounselorActivationTest::testActivationWithSubscriptionWithPasswordLogin
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:114
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php:326
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:547
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php:308
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\Concerns\InteractsWithElements.php:97
D:\devYubu\yubu\tests\Browser\tests\userActivation\CounselorActivationTest.php:58
D:\devYubu\yubu\vendor\laravel\dusk\src\TestCase.php:91
D:\devYubu\yubu\tests\Browser\tests\userActivation\CounselorActivationTest.php:95

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I'm using the value method 2 times, I can see that the first one actually fills in the form, however the second one fails..

```
->value('input[name=external_id]', $counselor->getAttribute(User::COLUMN_EXTERNAL_ID))
->value('input[name=name_full]', $counselor->getAttribute(User::COLUMN_NAME_FULL))
```

When I'm using type(), the first one also fails:

```
->type('external_id', $counselor->getAttribute(User::COLUMN_EXTERNAL_ID))
->type('name_full', $counselor->getAttribute(User::COLUMN_NAME_FULL))
```

In using Windows 10. I'm running Dusk on Windows (I have PHP 7.2 installed). My application runs on Homestead with PHP 7.0. I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: just wondering: could you be missing some value in phpunit.xml?

Comment: Could be a problem with an outdated ChromeDriver. The binaries provided by Dusk haven't updated in 10 months. Have you ever updated the ChromeDriver manually? If not, you can use [this package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/dusk-updater) I created.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, that worked, thanks!

Comment: Hello @JonasStaudenmeir - thank you for your package.  However... I can't get this working.  I run dusk:update, and I'm told

> ChromeDriver binaries successfully updated to version 2.41 (Chrome v67-69).


But running artisan dusk I see it's still using 2.33


> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64)


Any pointers to get it to use the new chromedriver?

Comment: Try restarting your (virtual) machine. Check the files in `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin`: Have they been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a problem with an outdated ChromeDriver.

Big thanks to Jonas Staudenmeir, who has created a package for updating your Chromedriver:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/dusk-updater

Comment: I ran staudenmeis updater - *BIG THANKS STAUDENMEIR* but it still wasn't working until I killed the old ChromeDriver Process. For those wondering how to kill this process run `ps -aux` then find the process ending with `/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux` the second parameter from the left on that line will be the PID (Process ID) copy it (and any other PID's of running chromeDrivers) and then kill each of them by running `kill #####` where ##### is the copied PID. Once all processes are killed - rerun dusk.

Answer (score 0):

I echo @Martijn Ihhoff. Get the staudenmeir updater -
https://github.com/staudenmeir/dusk-updater

After you download and run it (follow instructions on linked page above) be sure to kill the old ChromeDriver though. Here's how I did it:

run `ps -aux` then find the process ending with `/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux` the second parameter from the left on that line will be the `PID` (Process ID) copy it (and any other PID's of running chromeDrivers) and then kill each of them by running `kill #####` where `#####` is the copied PID. Once all processes are killed, re-run dusk.