# Dusk Test for Browser “DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist”

Tags: php, testing, laravel-dusk

I'm running the example test of Laravel Dusk for browser, but when I execute **php artisan dusk** I got an error

Using:
* Ubuntu 18
* Laravel 5.8
* Dusk 5.1
* ChromeDriver 74
* apache2

This is my DuskTestCase.php:

```
    <?php

    namespace Tests;

    use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

    abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
    {
    use CreatesApplication;

/**
 * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
 *
 * @beforeClass
 * @return void
 */
public static function prepare()
{
    static::startChromeDriver();
}

/**
 * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
 *
 * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
 */
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--no-sandbox'
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
        // 'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs()
        // 'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
    );
}
```

}

This is the error:

```
    1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
    Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.18.0-20-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Comment: Yes, no, but following some answers I got the solution with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541739/chromedriver-error-chrome-version-must-be-52-using-nightwatch/45227939#45227939

Comment: I had to change my chrome installation

Comment: Dusk defaults `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0`. If the actual display isn't on `:0` you will get the `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` error. Even if you have `DISPLAY` env variable set globally, php might not load it due to php configuration. Set DISPLAY in .env or make the graphical interface run on `:0`. This should be irrelevant if you are running headless.

Comment: @OscarAcevedoOsses my answer might help you too. You might have installed chromium-browser instead of google-chrome-stable.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I found out that I needed to add `--no-sandbox` to `tests/DuskTestCase.php` since I was running on root on an lxd container.

I found out about the error by running: `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --log-level=ALL` and in another terminal running `php artisan dusk`. It will display the logs and I was able to deduce the problem from there.

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly related to the question, but since I did not easily find any fix for the same error occuring on Laravel 7+ and Homestead 10.0.0, I'll present the solution I came up with after hours of research and trying hoping it will help out other people running into this issue.

#### Homestead configuration

Homestead does not seem to support Dusk out of the box anymore. To install the prerequisites for using Chromium, you have to add the webdriver feature to your `homestead.yaml`:

```
 features:
     - webdriver: true
```

and then re-provision by running `homestead halt && homestead up --provision`.

#### DuskTestCase class

After that, make sure Chromium is started in headless mode by adding additional arguments in the `driverChrome()` method in `tests/DuskTestCase.php`:

```php
    protected function driverChrome()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)
        );
    }
```

Most people will suggest using the `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flags too, but after provisioning homestead correctly with the webdriver feature that installs `google-chrome-stable` instead of `chromium-browser`, these were not needed for me to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try manually download ChromeDriver from
[official ChromeDriver downloads page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

```sh
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.88/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip    
./chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and solved it according to @Martins Balodis comment above. I'm guessing the reason is related to my dual monitor setup.
I did not manage to alter this by adding an entry in the Dusk's environment file. Instead, I added this line in the top section of my test file.

```
$_ENV['DISPLAY'] = getenv('DISPLAY');
```

I tested several suggestions concerning adding arguments to the chrome driver, but this was the only modification that worked given that I wanted to run the tests with `--browse`.